# Testing Stripe webhooks that require data on localhost

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments

The guide [here](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/fixed-price#manage-payment-authentication) says to monitor the `invoice.paid` event via webhook in order to provision a customers account when the payment is successful. How can I test fire the `invoice.paid` event with data? I need to be able to access the customer id and see what plan they purchased to provision it correctly.

I am able to test fire these events via the Stripe CLI, but I don't know how to fire them with mock data.

Answer (score 0):

With the [Stripe CLI](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-cli) you can trigger a `invoice.payment_suceeded` webhook event (which is almost exactly the same as `invoice.paid`):

```
stripe trigger invoice.payment_succeeded
```

That event will contain mock data. If you want to provide your own data, you'd have to mimic the event yourself. In that case you could do that by creating a new subscription in test mode, which will create an invoice and trigger the `invoice.paid` event.